# View file after uploading

Tags: php, yii2

How can I redirect the user to a view page after uploading file?

Now it works only when I write id of db entry in view

I'm totally new to php and yii 2.

Controller

```
   public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            if ($model->file && $model->validate()) { 
                $postFile   = Yii::$app->request->post();           
                $directory = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/uploads');
                $uid = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(6);
                $fileName = $uid . '.' . $model->file->extension;
                $filePath = $directory . '/' . $fileName;
                $path = 'http://frontend.dev/uploads/' . $fileName;
                $userinfo = new webminfo();
                $userinfo->uid = $uid;
                $userinfo->author_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
                $userinfo->path = $filePath;
                $userinfo->url = $path;
                $userinfo->created_at = time();
                $userinfo->ip = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP();
                $userinfo->save();
                if ($model->file->saveAs($filePath)) {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Success');
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $userinfo->uid]);             
               }   
            }
                else {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Error');
                }
        }
        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }

public function actionView($id) {
    $model = new webminfo();

return $this->render('view', [
            'id' => $id,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
}
```

View

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\webminfo;
$this->title = 'View';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>
```

Comment: your view will throw error if you are not passing `$id` as you have mandatory param in `actionView($id)`

Comment: @pravindot17 how can i pass it?

Comment: `return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $userinfo->uid]);` this is correct method, but did you check what value you are getting in `$userinfo->uid`, or else try `return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $uid]);`

Comment: @pravindot17 now it works, thank you.
But i need make url like `view?id=OXTC5G` and link to file with extension like OXTC5G.webm or OXTC5G.mp4.
How can i send two values from controller to a view?

Comment: I am glad, yes if you are passing id in controller then you need to keep the url like 'view?id=OXTC5G'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$uid` instead of `$userinfo->uid` as follows in your redirect function

```
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $uid]);
```